# How to make better Route structure in Angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a routing application as below. My application has Sign-in page and a main dashboard page. Inside dashboard there can be many children components as below flowering component. Will this workout or is there any better approach?

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'sign-in',
    component: SignInComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: SideNavComponent,
    children: [{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },

      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import ('./components/sidenav/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module')
          .then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'flowering',
        component: Flowering,
        canActivate: [RoleGuard],
        // children inside flowering
        children: [

          {
            path: 'inspection',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import ('./components/sidenav/pages/inspections/inspections.module')
              .then(m => m.InspectionsModule)
          },
          {
            path: 'test-results',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import ('./components/sidenav/pages/test-results/test-results.module')
              .then(m => m.TestResultsModule)
          },

        ]
      },


    ],
  },

];
```

Comment: I think this is a good structure, have you any problems with this?

Comment: @ArsenGalloghlyan no, I'm very new to angular. So practicing clean coding with better approach